# Unable to make sticky header in Angular app on iOS

Tags: css, angular

I have two sticky elements in my Angular App, one is the header and another is a DIV.

i'm using bootstrap so sticky class has the following css property:

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
}
```

The issue is that only the sticky div actually get's sticked while the header doesn't sticky..

My header looks like this:

```
<header class="section-header bg-white sticky">
  <ngb-progressbar *ngIf="isLoading" class="indeterminate" type="primary" [animated]="true" [value]="50" height=".2rem"></ngb-progressbar>
  <section class="header-main">
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

        <a href="" appHref class="brand-wrap" routerLink="/">
          <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" />
        </a>
        <div class="float-md-right">
          <div *ngIf="cart" class="widget-header">
            <a routerLink="/cart">
              <i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>
              <span class="icon-text">Carrello</span>
            </a>
            <span
              *ngIf="count != 0"
              class="badge badge-pill badge-danger notify"
              >{{ count }}</span
            >
          </div>
          <div class="widget-header" *ngIf="account">
            <a href="#" appHref>
              <i class="material-icons">person</i>
              <span class="icon-text">Accedi</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
```

While my sticky elements like this:

```
<section class="section-menu sticky">
  <nav class="nav justify-content-center">
    <a
      class="nav-link menu"
      href="#"
      appHref
      *ngFor="let men of menu; let i = index"
      (click)="clickMenu(men, i)"
      [class.active]="menuSelected === i"
      >{{ men.desc }}</a
    >
  </nav>
</section>
```

But only the section get sticked on iphone while on google chrome all works properly...

As you could see on the following GIF the header is sticky with `.section-menu` which is sticked when scrolling to the header, while on iphone the header is static and the only sticky element is `.section-menu`

[image]

Comment: a parent element of header needs a position other than static

Answer (score 0):

For Safari try using:

```
.sticky {
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
z-index: 3;
top: 0;
```

}

This is per Mozilla developer docs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this...[Sticky Header](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wsxu5v?file=src/app/app.component.css)

I have used a condition if window scroll < 150 then add a class "sticky".